# Getting error while installing Pillow in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to install `Pillow` in `Django`. But I am facing below error. I am using `mac os 10.15` catalina. Looking for some guidance on the same.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-record-sun2k_so/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/Pillow
         cwd: /private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/
    Complete output (172 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/setup.py", line 864, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/install.py", line 546, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
    raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/setup.py", line 918, in <module>
    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-install-w34kt0to/pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/_c/881z7d3138d5s14sgxctc_y40000gn/T/pip-record-sun2k_so/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please consider orgnizeing your question right, and just ask straight forward

Answer (score 0):

just use this command in your terminal

```
pip install pillow
or
pip3 install pillow
```

if first one doesn't work

Comment: i am getting this error after using both pip install Pillow and pip3 install Pillow

Comment: which version of python are u using 3.9?

Comment: if it is 3.9 (release 5 day before at 5 Oct 2020)then you have to wait for some time or install python 3.8 it support pillow and Django uses pillow for the image support

Comment: yes i am using python 3.9 thanks man

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html